# Preview PDF document

Tags: django

If I run:

> 127.0.0.1:8000/document/1/preview

this pdf file is downloaded.

I need display it in HTML(preview with print function). How to do it?

**views.py**

```
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from datetime import datetime
import StringIO

def pdf_report(request, did):
    d_instance = get_object_or_404(MyObject, pk=did, user=request.user)

    contents = render_to_string('pdf_preview.html', {'object':d_instance})
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=answer_%s.pdf' % (f_date,)
    result = StringIO.StringIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(contents.encode('utf-8')), result, show_error_as_pdf=True, encoding='UTF-8')
    if not pdf.err:
        response.write(result.getvalue())
        result.close()
        return response
```

**urls.py**

```
(r'^document/(?P<did>\d+)/preview/$', 'app.views.pdf_report'),
```

Comment: Do you want pdf file to open in a browser instead of downloading?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767567/how-to-open-a-generated-pdf-file-in-browser/3810925#3810925

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal What is `filename` in my case? I try `result` in `return render_to_response('pdf_preview.html',{'pdf':pdf, 'result':result},context_instance=RequestContext(request))` but this display `<StringIO.StringIO instance at 0xb4f66d8c>`

Comment: `<embed height="100%" width="100%"  name="plugin" src="{{ result }}"  type="application/pdf">`

Comment: in `src="{{ result }}"` result should be the path to pdf file.

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal `{{ result }}` is displayed like: `<StringIO.StringIO instance at 0xb4f66d8c>`. This is not a path.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31244/discussion-between-ankit-jaiswal-and-user2426362)

Comment: if you use jquery you may want to consider http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Comment: @Amyth This work by default in mozilla. Can I use this in other browsers?

Comment: @user2426362: This would work on all modern browsers that support `HTML5`. I have personally tested this in FF, chrome, safari. Do not remeber the versions though..

Answer (score 5):

To make the file open in the browser, use `inline` content-disposition.

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=answer_%s.pdf' % f_date
```

Comment: @user2426362, If this answer helped you, please consider marking as correct